# Spawning object over various times and at two random points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a spawner but I am getting the mechanics coded in before I actually spawn the object since I am assuming that will be the easier part.
So far I have created the code which works well yet the spawning points are heavily skewed to one of the two - ratios like 30:1 or more. False being the heavily skewed spawn.

```
timeLeftUntilSpawn = Time.time - startTime;
System.Random secondsBetweenSpawn = new System.Random ();
    float num2 = secondsBetweenSpawn.Next (1, 10); // random number between 1 and 10 'seconds'
    if (timeLeftUntilSpawn >= num2) {
        startTime = Time.time;
        timeLeftUntilSpawn = 0;
        Debug.Log ("Spawn one here");
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random (); // from here is deciding on the position of the spawn after one has been spawned
        int num = rnd.Next (0, 10); //random number between 0 and 10
        if (num < 5) {
            switchSpawning = false;
            Debug.Log ("False");
            transform.position = spawnPosition;
        } else if (num > 5) {
            switchSpawning = true;
            Debug.Log ("True");
            transform.position = spawnPosition2;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all your random number is an int... so you only have 10 possible numbers it can be.. 0 through 10  as whole numbers. Then you check if it is less than 5 or greater than 5... you have no condition for if the number *is* indeed... 5.

That's a 1 out of 10 chance that neither option will hit.

This is the reason you shouldn't use `else if`, but instead just use `else` alone in this situation.

Also there's no need to search for a number between 0 and 10, you can just search up to 1... try this:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random (); // from here is deciding on the position of the spawn after one has been spawned
    float num = rnd.Range (0, 1); //random number between 0 and 1
    if (num < .5f) {
        switchSpawning = false;
        Debug.Log ("False");
        transform.position = spawnPosition;
    } else {
        switchSpawning = true;
        Debug.Log ("True");
        transform.position = spawnPosition2;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks. By using a float rather than a int will that make the code more efficient when running ?

Comment: not necessarily, but in the way you were using it yes.